# Mahout RecommenderJob not converging

Tags: hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

This is my first SO post so please let me know if I've missed out anything important. I am a Mahout/Hadoop beginner, and am trying to put together a distributed recommendation engine.

In order to simulate working on a remote cluster, I have set up hadoop on my machine to communicate with a Ubuntu VM (using VirtualBox), also located on my machine, which has hadoop installed on it. This setup seems to be working fine and I am now trying to run Mahout's 'RecommenderJob' on a (very!) small trial dataset as a test.

The input consists of a `.csv` file (saved on the hadoop dfs) containing around 50 user preferences in the format: `userID, itemID, preference` ... and the command I am running is:

```
hadoop jar /Users/MyName/src/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=/user/MyName/Recommendations/input/TestRatings.csv -Dmapred.output.dir=/user/MyName/Recommendations/output -s SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORELLATION
```

where `TestRatings.csv` is the file containing the preferences and `output` is the desired output directory.

At first the job looks like it's running fine, and I get the following output:

```
12/12/11 12:26:21 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --maxPrefsPerUser=[10], --maxPrefsPerUserInItemSimilarity=[1000], --maxSimilaritiesPerItem=[100], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --numRecommendations=[10], --similarityClassname=[SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORELLATION], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
12/12/11 12:26:21 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/user/Naaman/Delphi/input/TestRatings.csv], --maxPrefsPerUser=[1000], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --output=[temp/preparePreferenceMatrix], --ratingShift=[0.0], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
12/12/11 12:26:21 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
12/12/11 12:26:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 
12/12/11 12:26:22 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: ShuffleRamManager: MemoryLimit=1491035776, MaxSingleShuffleLimit=372758944
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging on-disk files
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging in memory files
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread waiting: Thread for merging on-disk files
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for polling Map Completion Events
12/12/11 12:26:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
12/12/11 12:26:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/12/11 12:26:28 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > copy >
12/12/11 12:26:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > copy >
12/12/11 12:26:37 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > copy >
```

But then the last three lines repeat indefinitely (I left it overnight...), with the two lines:

```
12/12/11 12:27:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
12/12/11 12:27:22 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
```

repeating every twelve rows.

I'm not sure whether there's something wrong with my input, or whether the tiny size of the trial data is messing things up. Any help and/or advice on the best way to go about this would be much appreciated.

p.s. I was trying to follow the instructions from https://www.box.com/s/041rdjeh7sny128r2uki

Answer (score 1):

This is really a Hadoop or cluster issue. It is waiting on mapper output that is not coming. Look for earlier failures, in the mapping phase.

Comment: Hi Sean. Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I'm looking into the hadoop configuration now and will update with whatever solution I find. Looking forward to reading my new copy of Mahout in Action.